# Why does MYSQL get lock wait time out locally?

Tags: mysql, time, locking, out

I've run into lock wait time out errors several times and have learned that they can be a cumbersome issue.  I also noticed that I can be running a sql command in python script via shell and will issue this error. However, when connecting to the database via a GUI; I use sequel pro, that same query will not issue the lock out.  My question is why this happens?

Comment: care to share the SQL query that's locking the database?